# Make a one to Many relationship in ios using core data

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, ios5

I have two models :

```
Card with has_many relation to Works
```

I mean i have 7 static works in my database and i can choose some of them when i create a Card.

I defined a has_many relationship like this :

[image: Has many relationship]

My problem is strange... it seems to work, but when i explore my sqlite file, i don't see any table relationship between Card and Work.

I am expecting a table with card_id and work_id.

How core data store has many relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'd caution you from opening up the sqlite files Core Data spits out and trying to infer things from them. It's meant to be an opaque format: you're only supposed to interact with Core Data persistent stores through the Core Data APIs.

However, to answer your question: in general in database design, you wouldn't use a linking table like you describe for a one-to-many relationship, only for a many-to-many. For a one-to-many, you'd have a foreign key field in the table at the 'one' end, and have the contents of that field be the primary key of another table. For example (sorry for the random example I found on Google):

[image: one-to-many]

`tblOrder` is in a one-to-many relationship with `tblOrderDetails`. This is implemented by having an `Order#` field in the to-many side of the relationship, which is a foreign key referring to the primary key of the `tblOrder` table. As you can see, no linking table is needed.

A many-to-many relationship *would* need a linking table, but a one-to-many does not.

One final point: I note in your screenshot that you don't have an inverse relationship set up for your `works` or `customer` relationships. Core Data requires all relationships to have an inverse, otherwise your data may become corrupted. (That's somewhat a simplification, since there are other ways to work around it, but in general making inverses is easiest.)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am sorry but i think i am doing a many to many relationship in fact... How can i implement the linking table? I think core data generate it itself?

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, again I'll say that if it's working in Core Data land, don't mess with the underlying database: it's just an implementation detail how it handles the joins. But either way, you don't seem to have a many-to-many relationship in your screenshot, since a many-to-many relationship would definitely require an inverse. Add the inverse relationship (making sure that it is also -to-many) and look again?

Comment: Yes, i added an inverse and it's working fine, my link table is automatically created.